# Fetch complex table data from database

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a table in database and I want to fetch the data from it. I know how to fetch data from database using php. But the problem is that
this table is different in structure. For example

[image]
and so on...

As you can see this table is like a pivot table. That is the real problem for me. All the entries of a single person should be in single row. But it is in different rows and single column (all entries of single person is in `value` column).

I have tried to fetch table with regular way like this

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Registration
*/
get_header();

$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_cf_form_entry_values", ARRAY_A  );
$count = $results->num_rows;
if(!empty($results)) {
    echo "<table width='100%' border='1' cellspacing='1'>";
    echo "<tbody>";

    foreach($results as $row){
        echo "<tr>";              
        echo "<td><center>" . $row['value'] . "</center></td>";              
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</tbody>";
    echo "</table>"; 
} else {
    echo "<table width='100%' border='1' cellspacing='1'><tr><td>No Records Found</td></tr></table>";
}

get_footer();?>
```

But with the above code it's showing all the results in a single column and that's what I expect from above code.

So I don't know the correct code to represent this table as single row entries of single person. I searched a lot but didn't get much.

Comment: Please show the output you are expecting for

Comment: See the second column `entry_id`. I want all 5 in `entries id` should appear as one row and all 6 in `entry_id` should appear as second row and so on. Now see  fourth column `slug`. I want `slug` value should appear as column name AND last column `value` contains all values which i wants to show to user. I hope that makes sence

Comment: On more brief `first_name` (slug column's first value) is the column name and `sandeep` (value column's first value) is the value that comes under `first_name` column.

Comment: Did you try using a [DISTINCT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) statement or [UNIQUE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp) constraint?

Comment: @dingo I can't find out how these keywords can help me. I simply wants to show `slug` column's value as column name and `value` column's value as their values. Mean first make column `slug` horizontal and we will get column names and now make column `value` horizontal and we will get values in columns. thats what i want but not getting any idea.

Comment: You want all the values associated with one id, right? So you need to group them somehow. I'm guessing that you could group them according to distinct values of the `entry_id`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you looking for something like this:

**horizontal representation:** (by Person)

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Registration
*/
get_header();

global $wpdb;

//Create a mulit dimensional array for each person.
$persons = array();
$fields = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM wp_cf_form_entry_values');
foreach($fields as $field){
    $persons[$field->entry_id][$field->slug] = $field->value;
}

//the table
echo '<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="1">';
$i=0;
foreach($persons as $id=>$values){

    //the table header (only in the first loop)
    if($i==0){
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach($values as $key=>$val){
            echo '<th>'.$key.'</th>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }

    // one line per person
    echo '<tr id="'.$id.'">';
    foreach($values as $key=>$val){
        echo '<td>'.$val.'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
    $i++;
}

if($i==0){
   echo "<table width='100%' border='1' cellspacing='1'><tr><td>No Records Found</td></tr></table>";
}

echo '</table>';

get_footer();?>
```

**vertical representation** (by field slug)

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Registration
*/
get_header();

global $wpdb;

//Create a mulit dimensional array for each slug.
$field_slugs = array();
$fields = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM wp_cf_form_entry_values');
foreach($fields as $field){
    $field_slugs[$field->slug][$field->entry_id] = $field->value;
}

//the table
echo '<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="1">';
$i=0;
foreach($field_slugs as $slug=>$values){

    //the table header (only in the first loop)
    if($i==0){
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach($values as $person_id=>$val){
            echo '<th></th>';
            echo '<th>Person '.$person_id.'</th>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }

    // one line per person
    echo '<tr id="'.$slug.'">';
    echo '<td><b>'.$slug.'</b></td>';
    foreach($values as $person_id=>$val){
        echo '<td>'.$val.'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
    $i++;
}

if($i==0){
   echo "<table width='100%' border='1' cellspacing='1'><tr><td>No Records Found</td></tr></table>";
}

echo '</table>';

get_footer();?>
```

Comment: wow! thanks Nico Martin. That was perfect answer. But my requirements got change a little bit. May be I am asking too much but if possible can you please edit your answer to show me how I can show these data vertically instead of horizontally bcos I will show one person record at a time. Thats why vertical representation will be batter. BUT Please don't replace your above code. Its an excellent answer that will defiantly helps future viewers who will have same kind of problems. so kindly show your answer without replacing previous one. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You use foreign key entries_id so you can retrieve from that table ie

```
$results=$wpdb->get_results("select * from entries_table");
foreach($results as $result){
    $entries_id=$result->id;
    $entry_detail=$wpdb->get_results(SELECT * from form_field_table where entries_id='$entries_id' ");
        foreach($entry_detail as $ent_detail){?>
            <td><?php echo $ent_detial->slug;?></td><td><?php echo $ent_detial->value;?></td>
        <?php }
}
```